# Exchange Online issue with disclamer formatting

Tags: exchange, office365

I have been asked to look at adding a unified Mail footer to all our mailboxes.

However, the template they want to use is of the format.

```
<Name>
<email>
<Phone Number>
<Disclaimer Text>
```

If I manually create this in outlook on a client PC, it works as per the format. But if I go to Exchange Online -> Mail Flow -> rules And add a disclaimer in there, then it ends up as

```
<Name><email><Phone Number><Disclaimer Text>
```

So is there a way of enforcing Line breaks and text formatting in the disclaimer, or do I report back that they are pushing our version of Exchange further than it can go.

Comment: Pictures missing? If you can't inline yourself post to somewhere public, gyazo/imgur etc & someone can inline them for you.

Comment: Ah, no. Figured it out - need code formatting for <brackets>

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of symbol for showing placeholders :$

Comment: No Probs; it's the markdown SE uses. You *could* escape them all with \< \> etc - but that would get a bit tedious ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML formatting, so use 
 to break new lines

```
%%displayname%%</br>
%%Email%%</br>
%%PhoneNumber%%</br>
```

Comment: So easy I didn't think of it! Thanks